# Remove context menu items

Tags: macos

When I right click on a file and select open with, there are a bunch of irrelevant entries that I will never use. A lot of them are bits of the OS (e.g. Core Image Funhouse.app on image files) or at best dubious (I doubt I will ever want to open a .txt using Illustrator). Is there any way to remove items from the Open With menu? This is on OSX Lion 10.7.5.

The only questions I could find related to this were about uninstalled programs remaining in the context menu.

Thanks!

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5708820/how-to-clean-up-your-macs-open-with-contextual-menu

Comment: That will remove duplicates or leftovers from uninstalled programs, but what I want is to remove programs that are irrelevant to me (for that file type) without having to uninstall them (I still want to have Illustrator, I just don't want it to show up in the menu for a .txt).

Answer (score 1):

You could remove entries in the CFBundleDocumentTypes array in Info.plist files. To apply the changes, run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -f -R /Applications/` and reopen Finder.

Modifying an Info.plist breaks the code signature of signed applications and makes some applications like TextEdit crash on launch.