# Removing and adding items in context menu of Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, context-menu, office365

When I right click on an email I get a lengthy menu – including “Quick Print”, “Reply All”, etc. Out of these features I want only “Move”,”Delete” and “Categorize”. So how can I remove the unwanted menu items?

**Note**: I have referred similar questions like [Remove context menu items](https://superuser.com/questions/501782/remove-context-menu-items).  But I am looking for an approach that does not involve any programming and command execution.

[image]

Comment: Coding is involved.

Comment: [See if any suggestion here work](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-items-from-new-context-menu)